# Using IF..ELSE with multi INSERT INTO using Subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have two table on database related to each other through foreign key
table1 is journal
table2 is journalEntries
I have a query to check if there is row on current date from table journal if there is a record then it will insert record to journalEntries
if it is null then it will insert record on journal table1 then insert to journalEntries table2

I tried different way but it doesn't work

```
if (select j_id from journal where [date] > (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111))) is null
insert into journal values (getdate() as [date], getdate() as [insert_date], '' as notes)
insert into journalentries (j_id, acc_num, credit, debit, [user_id], note)
select (select (select j_id from Journal where [date] in (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111))) as j_id, @acc_num, @credit, @debit, @user_id, @note)

else
insert into journalentries (j_id, acc_num, credit, debit, [user_id], note)
select (select j_id from Journal where [date] in (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111))) as j_id, @acc_num, @credit, @debit, @user_id, @note
end
```

another way

```
if(select j_id from journal where [date] in ('2019-01-01')) is null
insert journal([date], insert_date, notes)
OUTPUT inserted.j_id, '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', ''
INTO dbo.journalentries(j_id, acc_num, credit, debit, [user_id], note)
values (j_id, @acc_num, @credit, @debit, @user_id, @note)
else
select (select j_id from Journal where [date] in (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111))) as j_id, @acc_num, @credit, @debit, @user_id, @note
```

Comment: what doesn't work?  Any particular error message?  Do you need to enclose the blocks within your IF ..... ELSE .... with BEGIN and END?

Comment: insert statment doesnt work, it didn't add a record it is give me an error in syntax in first block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used scop_identity() and it works

```
declare @j_id int = (select j_id from journal where [date] in (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)))
if @j_id is null
    begin 
    insert into journal values (getdate(), getdate(), '') set @j_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); insert into journalentries (j_id, acc_num, credit, debit, [user_id], note) values (@j_id, @acc_num, @credit, @debit, @user_id, '');
    end 
    else
    begin
    insert into journalentries (j_id, acc_num, credit, debit, [user_id], note)values (@j_id, @acc_num, @credit, @debit, @user_id, '')
    end
```

Comment: be careful if the first query returns multiple results, I would use `MAX(j_id)` or `TOP 1 j_id` to be safe

Answer (score 0):

just as a pointer, too long for a comment

```
    if (select j_id from journal where [date] > (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111))) is null
    begin 
    insert into journal  select getdate() as [date], getdate() as [insert_date], '' as notes;
    --insert into journalentries j_id, acc_num, credit, debit, [user_id], note); '!! where are you selecting this from?
    select (select (select j_id from Journal where [date] in (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111))) as j_id, @acc_num, @credit, @debit, @user_id, @note);
    end 
    else
    begin
    --insert into journalentries (j_id, acc_num, credit, debit, [user_id], note)  -- !! where are you selecting this from?
    select (select j_id from Journal where [date] in (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111))) as j_id, @acc_num, @credit, @debit, @user_id, @note
    end
```